# ODE: Arc length and Area in polar coordinates

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find $r=r(\theta)  $in polar coordinates such that the area between the radius $ r_o$ and $r_1$ is the ha'f of the arc length between the same radius

Answer: $csc(\theta+c)$

**My attempt**

We must have that
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{r_o}^{r_1} \sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2}d\theta =\frac{1}{2}\int_{r_o}^{r_1} r^2 d\theta$$

Derivating:

$$\sqrt{r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2} = r^2 $$

$$\Rightarrow r^2+\left(\frac{dr}{d\theta}\right)^2=r^4$$

$$\Rightarrow\frac{dr}{d\theta} = \sqrt{r^2(r^2-1)}$$

We could separate variables and solve. But I didnt had the given answer. What I've made wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Suppose $r>1$. Then you have
$$ \int \frac{dr}{r\sqrt{r^2-1}}=\theta+c$$
Let $u=r^2-1$ and then you will get the answer.

Comment: I've got arcsec as answer, not arccsc as desired. Am I wrong? http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28arcsec%28x%29%29%27&x=0&y=0

Comment: By the way, to solve this integral, I've used r=sec(t)

Comment: @Giiovanna, note that $\int\frac{dr}{r\sqrt{r^2-1}}=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{d(r^2-1)}{((r^2-1)+1)\sqrt{r^2-1}}$